# Show that $\sum r^n \cos(nx)=r\cos(x)-r^2/(1-2r\cos(x)+r^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm a little unsure about how to approach this.  I've been told that we have to use the relationship that $\sum r^n=1/1-r$. However, I'm not too sure what to do with the $\cos(nx)$.  Can someone give me some help?

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_n r^n\cos(nx)=\Re\sum_n r^ne^{inx}=\Re\sum_n(re^{ix})^n=\ldots$$

Answer (score 3):

Let me continue @Did answer.

$$\Sigma=\mathcal{R}\frac{1}{1-r\cdot e^{ix}}$$

Let us multiply numerator and denominator by $1-r\cdot e^{-ix}$. So

$$\Sigma=\mathcal{R}\frac{1-r\cdot e^{-ix}}{1-2r\cdot\mathcal{R}e^{ix}+r^2}=\frac{1-r\cos{x}}{1-2r\cos{x}+r^2}$$

Comment: Why do you only take the real component though?  What happens to the imaginary part?

Comment: Because the sum is the sum of $r^n\cos{x}=\mathcal{R}(r\cdot e^{ix})^n$