# Finding the value of trignometric series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{0}\dfrac{\cos nx}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

$Q. $ It is being given that $\cos x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ **and** $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{3}$ we need to find
$$\Sigma^{\infty}_{0}\dfrac{\cos nx}{3^n}$$

I tried writing some terms, and then *multiplying by three* and *subtracting original from it*, but that took me nowhere!

Then I tried using expansions of $\cos(nx)$ but realised this wasn't needed here and made it more unsolvable.

I also wanted to know if there was a more *general* method to *geometric-trigonometric* series like these

Comment: Please see the edit, $\cos (x) = \frac{1}{3}$ is also stated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230369/show-that-sum-rn-cosnx-rcosx-r2-1-2rcosxr2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\dfrac{\cos nx}{3^n}=\text{Re}\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}}{3}\right)^n= \text{Re} \: z^n
$$ with $\displaystyle z= \dfrac{e^{ix}}{3}$ then one may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n= \frac1{1-z},\quad |z|<1.
$$

Comment: How did you get that thought, i mean about making it into complex numbers! I struggled for about an hour manipulating trigonometry!

Comment: I think, this is indeed one of the very first exercises teachers give just after studying $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ formula.

Comment: Oh, but this problem was on a trigonometry paper, so never thought of that!